# Why isn't my contract getting a msg.sender? (solc 0.2.0-1)

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

**TL;DR:** Second's `msg.sender` isn't being set when it should.

Consider these two contracts:

First.sol:

```
import "Second.sol";

contract First {
  address public second;

  function First() {

  }

  function createSecond() {
    second = address(new Second());
  }
}
```

Second.sol:

```
contract Second {
  address public sender;

  function Second() {
    sender = msg.sender;
  }
}
```

When I send a transaction to First's `createSecond()`, then get the Second's address and try to get the sender of Second, I get `0x0` returned instead of an address.

Perhaps this is best shown in a test. Here, I'm using [Truffle](https://github.com/ConsenSys/truffle) to run the test, and the `First` and `Second` objects are provided by Truffle through [ether-pudding](https://github.com/ConsenSys/ether-pudding).

```
contract('First -', function(accounts) {
  it("Second should have an sender on creation", function(done) {
    var first, second;
    console.log("Creating first...");
    First.new().then(function(instance) {
      first = instance;

      console.log("Creating second...");
      return first.createSecond();
    }).then(function(tx) {
      console.log("Getting Second's address...");
      return first.second.call();
    }).then(function(second_address) {
      console.log(second_address);
      second = Second.at(second_address);
      console.log("Getting Second's sender...");
      return second.sender.call();
    }).then(function(sender) {
      console.log("SENDER ADDRESS:", sender);
      assert.notEqual(sender, "0x0");
    }).then(done).catch(done);
  });
});
```

Which produces this output:

```
Using environment test.
Compiling contracts...


  Contract: First
    Creating first...
    Creating second...
    Getting Second's address...
    0xbf12bb70b9bb9e1b58984a4ba5331a118d622d86
    Getting Second's sender...
    SENDER ADDRESS: 0x0
    1) Second should have an admin on creation.
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (2s)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: First - Second should have an sender on creation:
     AssertionError: expected '0x0' to not equal '0x0'
```

So as you can see, Second's `msg.sender` isn't being set when it should. Anyone know why?

My environment:

- OS X El Capitan
- solc 0.2.0-1 via npm
- Confirmed with ethereumjs-testrpc and Geth/v1.3.2-54904379/darwin/go1.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright. It looks like it was a very subtle bug in an edited version ether-pudding, causing this code `Second.at(second_address);` to be given the wrong address. In debugging I had mistakenly attributed the error the wrong cause (i.e., solc 0.2.0-1). Closing the question.

Answer (score 2):

This might be related to a recent optimizer bug (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/333) that was fixed.

To get the latest solc in Truffle. Download: https://github.com/chriseth/browser-solidity/blob/gh-pages/bin/soljson-latest.js. And stick into /node_modules/solc/bin.

I ran it with solc at 20f7458 and it worked fine.